# Rails JSON request is not parsed correctly into post parameters

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer

I'm trying to debug a problem where Rails isn't decoding the JSON POST data.

The server logs show:

```
2011-12-14T06:44:44+00:00 app[web.2]: Started POST 
2011-12-14T06:44:44+00:00 app[web.2]:   Processing by PostsController#create as */*
2011-12-14T06:44:44+00:00 app[web.2]:   Parameters: {"{\"athlete_id\":\"\",\"known_as\":\"abc\",\"email\":\"abc@defg.com\",\"result\":\"112233\",\"rx\":false,\"mods\":\"thkjth\",\"notes\":\"\"}"=>nil, "affiliate_id"=>"testaffiliate", "wod_id"=>"12345"}
```

Note that the JSON string is not being parsed - Rails is assigning it as a key in the hash, pointing to a nil value.  Does anyone have any ideas before I write a before_filter that tries to JSON.parse all of the params keys?

I don't think this is relevant since I'm sending and receiving data okay, but this problem occurs during a CORS Request from IE (using XDomainRequest).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
before_filter :fix_ie_params, only: [:create, :update]
```

For **Thin**:

```
def fix_ie_params
  if request.format == '*/*'
    # try to JSON decode in case of IE XDR
    begin

      params.merge! ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body.string)

    rescue Exception=>e
      # todo: log exception
    end
  end
end
```

For **Unicorn** and **Phusion Passenger**:

```
def fix_ie_params
  if request.format == '*/*'
    # try to JSON decode in case of IE XDR
    begin

      request.body.rewind
      params.merge! ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body.read)

    rescue Exception=>e
      # todo: log exception
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I found that doing this (on unicorn) I the body of the request included in the params as a key: `{'theBodyOfRequest' => nil, :controller => users, :action => 'update'}` Depending on your use case this might cause problems. As it's the first param, I added `params.shift` to remove it.

Comment: @collin, yeah - The data I was POSTing was originally JSON `{:foo => "bar"}`  (which was stringified for sending) so the params at the controller looked like: `{"{\"foo\" => \"bar\"} => nil, "controller" => "users" ...}`

Comment: @Peter, that sounds like the original problem I described in the question, doesn't it?  Are you sure that your filter is being run?

Comment: @collin, sorry, my first comment is not clear (can't update now). The filter is being run, and the parameters are being put where I expected them (the answer works). However, the body also remains present as a key, e.g. {"{\"foo\" => \"bar\"} => nil, "controller" => "users", :action => :new, :foo => "bar"}. This caused me issues, so thought I'd mention it. This was using CORS too - oh, the pain.

Comment: @Peter - Ah, ok.  I guess that's expected behavior then.  Out of curiosity, how did that cause issues?

Comment: @collin, It was when I was investigating - I think I had bypassed the strong params and was trying to manipulate all parameters. I think trying to parse the body as a key was causing issues.

Answer (score 17):

You can get past this by setting the Content-Type header to "application/json". You can let the controller know what it expects to return with the Accept header set to "application/json".

The following command with both headers:

```
curl -d '{ "company": { "name": "acme", "address": "123 Carrot Street" } }' http://0.0.0.0:3000/mysite --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Generates this in the logs:

```
Started POST "/mysite" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-11 16:09:48 -0800
  Processing by MyController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"company"=>{"name"=>"acme", "address"=>"123 Carrot Street"}, "wassup"=>{"company"=>{"name"=>"acme", "address"=>"123 Carrot Street"}, "controller"=>"wassup", "action"=>"create"}}
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 2.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

---

This command with the Accept header:

```
curl -d '{ "company": { "name": "acme", "address": "123 Carrot Street" } }' http://0.0.0.0:3000/mysite --header "Accept: application/json"
```

Generates these logs:

```
Started POST "/mysite" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-11 16:07:26 -0800
  Processing by MyController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"{ \"company\": { \"name\": \"acme\", \"address\": \"123 Carrot Street\" } }"=>nil}
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

---

And finally this command with the Content-Type header:

```
curl -d '{ "company": { "name": "acme", "address": "123 Carrot Street" } }' http://0.0.0.0:3000/mysite --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Generates these logs:

```
Started POST "/mysite" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-11 16:08:11 -0800
  Processing by MyController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"company"=>{"name"=>"acme", "address"=>"123 Carrot Street"}, "wassup"=>{"company"=>{"name"=>"acme", "address"=>"123 Carrot Street"}, "controller"=>"wassup", "action"=>"create"}}
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 2.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Notice the parsed parameters and processing message change subtly with each header type.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!  Unfortunately, with XDomainRequest I don't have control over the headers. (See items 3 and 4 in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx).) So I think this is probably the correct answer, but doesn't quite solve my problem.  Do you know if there's any way to tell the controller to assume everything is a JSON request?  Or at least set the default content-type to JSON?

Comment: The json gets parsed into the params member (in rails 3.1) in params_parser.rb which holds ActionDispatch::ParamsParser and is a piece of middleware. You could add another piece of middleware which infers the incoming request type and sets it appropriately.

However, if you are going to do that you might as well just put some logic in the controller to do that for your particular code and not alter the rest of the middleware stack.